# SharePoint is not AD aware

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint

I did not install or configure SharePoint on this box but it is in a domain. After creating a web application and site collection, I can not add domain users to the site collection. The OS is AD aware, and I tested this by creating a local group and adding a domain user into that group.

How can I ensure that SharePoint is aware of the domain?

**Windows Server 2008/MOSS 2007**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out the solution to my own problem. The SharePoint site collection was running in an application pool with local credentials instead of domain credentials.

Answer (score 3):

In Central Administration, you need to go into the Application Management. Once there, look for Authentication Providers, under Application Security. You should have a Default zone, open that and you will be able to pick your authentication type.

Comment: Currently the site is set to: Authentication Type: Windows; Intergrated Windows Authentication: checked; NTLM: Checked; Enable Client Intergration: Yes;

With those settings, all should be well. Unfortunately its not.

Comment: Have you added users to the site itself? When you are in the web app, go to site settings, then look under advanced permissions. Try adding a test user there.

Comment: That is what I mean when I say "I can not add users to the site collection"

Comment: This answer is incorret because without an authentication provider set up deverop wouldn't be able to access the site collection in the first place.